# Group a array by another array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

Let say i have 2 array with the same length in JavaScript

```
Array_1 : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'E']

Array_2 : ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2', '10']
```

Now how can i group by Array_1 and Array_2 together ?

Meaning the result will be like this:

```
Array_1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

Array_2: ['8',  '7', '8', '3', '18', '6', '9']
```

Thanks

Comment: Despite your example, I have no clue what you mean by "group by". It looks like you have removed duplicates in the first array, but I cannot fathom what you've done with the second to get those values. Could you please explain?

Comment: @RolandWeber In SQL it will be like this Select Array_1 Sum(Array_2) Group by Array_1

Comment: So you're looking for someone who is familiar with both SQL and JavaScript to understand and answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by group by you mean adding values with same keys together you could try:

```js
let a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'E'];
let b = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2', '10'];

const temp = {};
a.forEach((value, index) => {
    temp.hasOwnProperty(value) ? temp[value]+=parseInt(b[index]) : temp[value]=parseInt(b[index]);
});

a = Object.keys(temp);
b = Object.values(temp);
console.log(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and group arrays in key value form.

```js
let Array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'E']
let Array2 = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2', '10']

let op = Array1.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
  if(op[inp]){
    op[inp] += Number(Array2[index])
  } else {
    op[inp] = Number(Array2[index])
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.keys(op))
console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and splice items if the value is known and update `array2`.

This proposal uses number instead of string because the numbers a better to add.

It uses an object for keeping track of the indices.

```js
var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'E'],
    array2 = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2', '10'].map(Number),
    indices = {},
    index = 0,
    value;
    
while (index < array1.length) {
    value = array1[index];
    if (value in indices) {
        array2[indices[value]] += array2[index];
        array1.splice(index, 1);
        array2.splice(index, 1);
        continue;
    }
    indices[value] = index;
    index++;
}
console.log(array1.join(' '));
console.log(array2.join(' '));
```

A bit shorter by taking a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'E'],
    array2 = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2', '10'].map(Number),
    map = array1.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + array2[i]), new Map);

array1 = Array.from(map.keys());
array2 = Array.from(map.values(), String);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```